# node-red / function to calculate and return number

Tags: node-red

battling with what i think must be a trivial thing (and thus my trivial mistake - i m still new to node-red):

in node-red, trying to have a simple function to put payload
such as [ 250, 8 ]
into an array, perform a simple calculation, and return a result, like so:

```
var msgAll = { payload: msg.payload};
var msg0 = { payload :msg.payload[0] };
var msg1 = { payload :msg.payload[1] };
var msg2 = msg0 + msg1;
return [ msg0, msg1, msg2];
```

msg0 and msg1 get returned as number:

```
msg.payload : number
250
msg.payload : number
8
```

whereas msg2 is undefined

```
msg.payload : undefined
undefined
```

what am i missing about types, payloads, returning?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can not add 2 JavaScript objects together. If you want to add the 2 `msg.payload` values you need to explicitly add those 2 variables.

```
var msgAll = { payload: msg.payload};
var msg0 = { payload :msg.payload[0] };
var msg1 = { payload :msg.payload[1] };
var msg2 = {payload: msg0.payload + msg1.payload};
return [ msg0, msg1, msg2];
```

Comment: thanks, @hardillb, that clarified and solved it. 
the concept of object vs. the type of the object's payload still wasn't clear to me.